# Contradictory definitions about the Order of Constant Initialization and Zero Initialization in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, compile-time-constant, constant-expression

I have been trying to understand how static variables are initialized. And noted a contradiction about the order of constant initialization and zero initialization at [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization) and  [enseignement](https://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF478/docs/Cpp/en/cpp/language/constant_initialization.html).

At [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization) it says:

> Constant initialization is performed **instead** of zero initialization of the static and thread-local (since C++11) objects and before all other initialization.

Whereas at [enseignement](https://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF478/docs/Cpp/en/cpp/language/constant_initialization.html) it says:

> Constant initialization is performed **after** zero initialization of the static and thread-local objects and before all other initialization.

So as you can see cppref uses "instead" while the second site uses "after". **Which of the two is correct?** That is, does zero initialization **always** happen first and then if possible constant initialization as implied by the second site or the other way round.

The example given there is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
 
struct S {
    static const int c;
};
const int d = 10 * S::c; // not a constant expression: S::c has no preceding
                         // initializer, this initialization happens after const
const int S::c = 5;      // constant initialization, guaranteed to happen first
int main()
{
    std::cout << "d = " << d << '\n';
    std::array<int, S::c> a1; // OK: S::c is a constant expression
//  std::array<int, d> a2;    // error: d is not a constant expression
}
```

This is my understanding of the initialization process so far:

1. Static initialization happens first. This includes

- Constant initialization if possible
- Zero initialization only if constant initialization was not done

2. Dynamic Initialization

Now according to the above(my understanding) this is how the code above works:

**Step 1.**

When the control flow reaches the definition of `const int d` it sees that the initializer has a variable(namely `S::c`) that has not been already initialized. So the statement `const int d = 10 * S::c;` is a dynamic time(runtime) initialization. This means it can only happen after static initialization. And ofcourse `d` is not a constant expression.

**Step 2.**

The control flow reaches the definition of variable `const int S::c;` . In this case however the initializer is a constant expression and so constant initialization can happen. And there is no need for zero initialization.

**Step 3.**

But note that we(the compiler) still haven't initialized the variable `d` because it left its initialization because it has to be done dynamically. So now this will take place and `d` will get value 50. But note `d` still isn't a constant expression and hence we cannot use it where a constant expression is required.

**Is my analysis/understanding of the concept correct and the code behaves as described?**

## Note:

The order of constant initialization and zero initialization is also different at [cppref-init](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) and [enseignement-init](https://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF478/docs/Cpp/en/cpp/language/initialization.html).

Comment: your enseignement link is simply an old copy of the cpp reference page from 7 years ago: https://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/language/constant_initialization&oldid=71426

Comment: you can see on https://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF474A/docs/Cpp/en/index.html its a copy from August 2014

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When in doubt, turn to the standard. As this question is tagged with C++11, we'll refer to [N3337](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337).

[[basic.start.init]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/basic.start.init#2):

> Variables with static storage duration ([basic.stc.static]) or thread
> storage duration ([basic.stc.thread]) **shall be zero-initialized**
> ([dcl.init]) **before any other initialization takes place.**
>
> Constant initialization is performed: [...]
>
> **Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called
> static initialization;** all other initialization is dynamic
> initialization. Static initialization shall be performed before any
> dynamic initialization takes place.

Thus, with regard to the C++11 Standard, enseignement's description is accurate.

> Constant initialization is performed after zero initialization of the static and thread-local objects and before all other initialization.

However, this was flagged as *a defect* as per [CWG 2026](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue2026):

> CWG agreed that constant initialization should be considered as happening instead of zero initialization in these cases, making the declarations ill-formed.

And as of C++17 ([N4659](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659)) this was changed, and henceforth governed by [[basic.start.static]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.start.static#2):

> [...] Constant initialization is performed if a variable or temporary object with static or thread storage duration is initialized by a constant initializer for the entity. **If constant initialization is not performed**, a variable with static storage duration or thread storage duration **is zero-initialized.** Together, zero-initialization and constant initialization are called static initialization; all other initialization is dynamic initialization.

But as this was not just new standard feature update, but a defect, it backports to older standard, and in the end cppreference's description is accurate also for C++11 (in fact all the way back to C++98), whereas enseignement's has not taken into account neither modern C++ standard nor the DR CWG 2026.

I have never visited enseignement's page myself, but after a quick glance at their reference page, it looks like a really old version of cppreference itself, **either entirely unattributed** to cppreference, or cppreference actually started as a collab with the enseignement authors.

Short of the standard itself I consider cppreference to be a de facto reference, and given the old copy-pasta of enseignement I would recommend never to turn to those for pages reference again. And indeed, we may visit [the actual up-to-date cppreference page on constant initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_initialization), scroll to the very bottom and read:

> #### Defect reports
>
> The following behavior-changing defect reports were applied
> retroactively to previously published C++ standards.
>
> [...]
>
> - **CWG 2026**
>
>   - *Applied to:* C++98
>   - *Behavior as published:* zero-init was specified to always occur first, even before constant-init
>   - *Correct behavior:* no zero-init if constant init applies